# Using CefSharp to capture Resource Response Data (body)

Tags: cefsharp

I am trying to use CefSharp to visit a URL and capture specific resources retrieved during the loading of a given page. Presumably as a Stream or byte array per resource.

CefSharp provides the interface IRequestHandler. You can create a class which implements this interface to respond to Request/Response events, but it does not contain the response body in any way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at `GetResourceResponseFilter` in your implementation of `IRequestHandler`. `GetResourceResponseFilter` returns an `IResponseFilter`, which provides you with an opportunity to capture all responses. You'll need to implement your own `IResponseFilter`, thankfully there are ample examples.

[Example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/Filters/MemoryStreamResponseFilter.cs) `IResponseFilter` implementation taken from the `CefSharp` GitHub project.

```cs
public class MemoryStreamResponseFilter : IResponseFilter
{
        private MemoryStream memoryStream;

        bool IResponseFilter.InitFilter()
        {
            //NOTE: We could initialize this earlier, just one possible use of InitFilter
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
             
            return true;
        }

        FilterStatus IResponseFilter.Filter(Stream dataIn, out long dataInRead, Stream dataOut, out long dataOutWritten)
        {
            if (dataIn == null)
            {
                dataInRead = 0;
                dataOutWritten = 0;

                return FilterStatus.Done;
            }

            dataInRead = dataIn.Length;
            dataOutWritten = Math.Min(dataInRead, dataOut.Length);

            //Important we copy dataIn to dataOut
            dataIn.CopyTo(dataOut);

            //Copy data to stream
            dataIn.Position = 0;
            dataIn.CopyTo(memoryStream);

            return FilterStatus.Done;
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            memoryStream.Dispose();
            memoryStream = null;
        }

        public byte[] Data
        {
            get { return memoryStream.ToArray(); }
        }
    }
```

Now in your `GetResourceResponseFilter` method:

```cs
 private Dictionary<ulong, MemoryStreamResponseFilter> responseDictionary = new Dictionary<ulong, MemoryStreamResponseFilter>();
 public IResponseFilter GetResourceResponseFilter(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
 {
       var dataFilter = new MemoryStreamResponseFilter();
       responseDictionary.Add(request.Identifier, dataFilter);
       return dataFilter;
 }
```

Then in `OnResourceLoadComplete`:

```cs
public void OnResourceLoadComplete(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response, UrlRequestStatus status, long receivedContentLength)
{      
    MemoryStreamResponseFilter filter;
    if (responseDictionary.TryGetValue(request.Identifier, out filter))
    {
        var data = filter.Data; //This returns a byte[]
        //File.WriteAllBytes("c:/save/path", data);
    }
}
```

You can use the properties within the `IRequest` and `IResponse` parameters to decide what you want to filter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and examples TEK. I am now much closer to my final solution. I had the IResponseFilter class ready, but didn't know how/where to use it.
Just wondering why the particular resource I am looking for never shows up in the OnResourceLoadComplete event. I suspect it's a javascript post to the server. Any special needed to capture those?
I can see them all in Chrome Developer Tools when browsing the site.

Comment: @FritsDonkerbroek  It should capture everything. You can try adding a simple `if(response.ResourceType == ResourceType.Xhr)` which should catch the `XMLHttpRequest` (which I assume is what you're after). If that is the case, then you will need to periodically poll the `responseDictionary`, as `OnResourceLoadComplete` will fire every time a resource is loaded (including a dynamic `Xhr`). You can also take a look at `response.ResponseHeaders` and see if is coming back to you.

Comment: Yep it's Xhr data I am after. Been logging the URL's for the Xhr requests, and I can see some of the ones I see in Chrome Dev Tools, but not the ones I am after. To date the only thing I have found that captures this particular data is SlimerJs which is not ideal. I will continue to dig around but suspect this one is a lost cause. Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: This was very helpful.  I modified mine to be a dictionary of Frame Objects, with a dictionary of resource objects (Objects I made up) so that my resources are groups by frame with their content.  I also use this to get all the HTML instead of using Frame.GetSourceAsync, much easier, since I already have the content now.

Comment: In the above example, the `FilterStatus IResponseFilter.Filter()` code is incorrect. This code throws an exception in situations where DataIn is larger than DataOut. See: **honestabelink** comment on this [link](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2433) page

Comment: CefSharp now has a default implementation for capturing data to a MemoryStream see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#response-filtering for an example